# Problemas en android studio calculando el total

Tags: php, java, android, xml

Quiero crear una app de android que me calcule un valor total. La app deberia tomar el valor del subtotal que se obtiene a través de un intent y el descuento y a partir de ahi, calcular el iva y el total. Para esto, se envian los datos a un codigo php para que realice los calculos. Sin embargo, todo parece indicar que los datos no se están enviando correctamente al codigo php, puesto que no me devuelve ningun valor. Podrían ayudarme con esto? adjunto foto para hacerme entender mejor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el java:

```html
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;

public class Activity_Pasarela_De_Pagos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerViewpasarela;
    private PasarelaAdapter adapter;
    private List<Productos> productos;
    private TextView txt_subtotal_pasarela;
    private TextView txt_iva_pasarela;
    private TextView txt_domicilio_pasarela;
    private TextView txt_total_pasarela;

    private TextView txtDescuento;

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String API_URL = "xxxxxx";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pasarela_de_pagos);

        recyclerViewpasarela = findViewById(R.id.recycler_pasarela);
        recyclerViewpasarela.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        productos = Carrito_De_Compras.getInstance().getProductos();

        txt_subtotal_pasarela = findViewById(R.id.Txt_Subtotal_Pasarela);
        txt_iva_pasarela = findViewById(R.id.Txt_Iva_Pasarela);
        txt_domicilio_pasarela = findViewById(R.id.Txt_Domicilio_Pasarela);
        txt_total_pasarela = findViewById(R.id.Txt_Total_Pasarela);
        txtDescuento = findViewById(R.id.Txt_Descuento_Pasarela);

        String stringSubtotal = getIntent().getStringExtra("Subtotal");
        txt_subtotal_pasarela.setText(stringSubtotal);

        adapter = new PasarelaAdapter(productos);
        recyclerViewpasarela.setAdapter(adapter);

        sendRequestToAPI(stringSubtotal, txtDescuento.getText().toString());
    }

    private void sendRequestToAPI(String subtotal, String descuento) {
        try {
            JSONObject requestData = new JSONObject();
            requestData.put("subtotal", subtotal);
            requestData.put("descuento", descuento);

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL, requestData,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                String iva = response.getString("iva");
                                String domicilio = response.getString("domicilio");
                                String total = response.getString("total");

                                txt_iva_pasarela.setText(iva);
                                txt_domicilio_pasarela.setText(domicilio);
                                txt_total_pasarela.setText(total);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("API Request", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(request);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (requestQueue != null) {
            requestQueue.cancelAll(this);
        }
    }
}
```

este es su xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_Pasarela_De_Pagos">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_pasarela"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="241dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="238dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/adidas" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView60" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView60"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Tu dirección"
                android:textColor="#0C0C0C"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView66" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView61"
                android:layout_width="430dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Descuento"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView67"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textColor="#090909"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Txt_Propina" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView63"
                android:layout_width="376dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:text="Domicilio"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView64" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView64"
                android:layout_width="378dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:text="Iva (19%)"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView65" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView65"
                android:layout_width="376dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:text="Subtotal"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView61" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView66"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="Resumen:"
                android:textColor="#070707"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:text="Confirmar pedido"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView67" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:text="Aplicar código"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_pasarela">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Código promocional" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Txt_Subtotal_Pasarela"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Txt_Descuento_Pasarela"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0%"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Txt_Iva_Pasarela"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Txt_Subtotal_Pasarela" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Txt_Domicilio_Pasarela"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView64" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/Txt_Propina"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Propina"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView63">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Txt_Total_Pasarela"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#0B0A0A"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Txt_Propina" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

y este es el codigo php:

```html
<?php

// Obtener los parámetros enviados desde la aplicación
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$descuento = $_POST['descuento'];
$propina = $_POST['propina'];

// Imprimir los valores obtenidos
echo "Subtotal: " . $subtotal . "\n";
echo "Descuento: " . $descuento . "\n";
echo "Propina: " . $propina . "\n";

// Convertir los valores a números
$subtotal = (float) str_replace(',', '', substr($subtotal, 1)); // Remover el símbolo $ y las comas
$descuento = (float) str_replace('%', '', $descuento); // Remover el símbolo %
$propina = (float) str_replace(',', '', substr($propina, 1)); // Remover el símbolo $

// Calcular el total con descuento
$totalDescuento = $subtotal - ($subtotal * ($descuento / 100));

// Calcular el valor del IVA sobre el total con descuento
$iva = $totalDescuento * 0.19;

// Definir el valor del domicilio
$domicilio = 8000; // Valor estático de $8000

// Calcular el total final sumando el valor del IVA, el domicilio y la propina
$total = $totalDescuento + $iva + $domicilio + $propina;

// Crear un arreglo con los datos calculados
$response = array(
    'subtotal' => number_format($subtotal, 2),
    'descuento' => $descuento,
    'iva' => number_format($iva, 2),
    'domicilio' => number_format($domicilio, 2),
    'propina' => number_format($propina, 2),
    'total' => number_format($total, 2)
);

// Convertir el arreglo a formato JSON y enviar la respuesta
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

y este es el resultado de la impresión:

Subtotal: Descuento: Propina: {"subtotal":null,"descuento":null,"iva":0,"domicilio":8000,"propina":null,"total":8000}

Comment: Hola. ¿Has depurado `requestData` y verificado que ahí los datos son correctos? Luego, en el servidor intentas recuperar esto: `$_POST['propina']` pero no estás mandando nada con una clave llamada `propina`. Conviene que revises el Logcat, pues ahí deberías obtener más detalles del error.